# Some (Python) dbf fields are filled with None. Why?

Tags: python, dbf

In the following code, I'm testing some numeric fields, but a `TypeError` is being thrown.

```
import dbf

dbf_orders = dbf.Table('../../data/ORDERS.DBF')
idx_orders_OrDtTm = dbf_orders.create_index(lambda rec: str(rec.ODATE) + rec.OTIME.decode('utf-8') + formatRecNo(rec))

thisRec_Orders = idx_orders_OrDtTm.current_record

if thisRec_Orders['Received'] > 0 \
        and (thisRec_Orders['oTotal'] + thisRec_Orders['Change']) < thisRec_Orders['Received']:
```

The `Change` field has a value of `None`, but the data type is numeric. Output from `Table.structure()` shows `'CHANGE N(7,2) BINARY'`.

However, the value of the `Change` field is not always `None`. Most of the time, the field *does* have a numeric value.

*And*, it's generally annoying that character fields are represented as binary.

Is there a way to get the data types in a record with valid data for their field types? I would expect this to be the default action.

I don't want to have to check every field for valid data before I use it. I could write a routine to fix data types and values when assigning `current_record` to a variable, but I'm hoping there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `None` can be returned is that it is possible to have a field be empty.  For example, Logical fields *should be* `T` or `F`, but can be `' '` (a space).  If `empty` is not a valid value for the field type, then `None` is returned (e.g. nothing but spaces *is* a valid value for a Character field).

The best solution to that problem is for the creating program to store valid values in the fields.

The next best solution is to tell `dbf` which type you want when nothing is stored in the field:

```
... = dbf.Table('...', default_data_types={'N': int, 'L':bool})
```

and probably create your own function to return tables with your default settings.

---

Note:  the specification for the `default_data_types` parameter is

```
{ data-type: python-type-for-any-or-no-value,
  data-type: (python-type-for-any-value, python-type-for-no-value),
  data-type: (python-type-for-any-value, python-type-for-no-value, python-type-for-null),
  }
```

If less than all three types are specified, the last one is used to fill out the triple -- so `'N': int` is the same as `'N': (int, int, int)`, meaning that whatever was stored in the field, you'll get an `int` back.

---

Note:  some data types, such as `date.date` and `date.datetime` do not have an `empty`/`0` possibility, and calling them without a value raises a `ValueError` or a `TypeError`.

---

Note: The field is showing `BINARY` because it has the binary flag set in the field header in the dbf file.

Comment: Thank you @ethan! I guess Clipper _displays_ default values for empty fields, and even lets you test for those phantom values. I'm stuck with the binary flag setting because I have to use the dbf files as-is. I did end up writing code that would create a case-insensitive (I liked that feature in your system) dictionary copy of `current_record`, with appropriate data types (and default values when empty). It's working well, for now. Thank you, again!